# Dropbox Core API, notification if a file has been added to a folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I have an app that creates tickets by putting a file in a Dropbox folder. Based on this ticket a file is added to another (Dropbox) folder. I use the Dropbox Core API.

Now, I have to refresh the folder manually to see if the new file already has been added.
I am searching for a method to be notified when the folder is changed (a file has been added) but haven't found it. I guess *longpoll_delta* can do the job but that isn't available in the iOS API.

Is there a method to do this in Objective-c?

I retrieve the data the following way:

```
- (void) refreshTable {
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"path"];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    for (DBMetadata * child in metadata.contents) {
        if (!child.isDirectory && !child.isDeleted) {
            NSLog(@"Filename: %@", child.filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the relationship between a ticket and the client app/user?

Comment: The user logs on in the app and by pressing a button he/she can create a ticket (a ticket is a file containing a JSON structure). This ticket is then processed and a response is created as a file in a certain dropbox folder. I want to 'subscribe' to updates of this folder.
I read that webhooks can be used for this purpose but I can not find how to do that in Objective-C

Comment: Webhooks is a good solution for notifications of changes for server-side apps. For client-side apps, such as yours on iOS, the /longpoll_delta endpoint is a good solution. As you noted, that's not currently available in the official Dropbox iOS Core SDK. Note that the SDK is open source though, so you can modify it if/as desired.

Comment: Am I the first one who tries to use /longpoll_delta in objective-c?

Comment: Did you get this working? I too need a callback when files change as I was using the deprecated Sync API. And @Greg, I'm not up to modifying the SDK for this.

Comment: No, I didn't get this working. I just added a manual refresh button to the App. That also worked.But, if anyone has a solution please let is know.

Answer (score 0):

The new Dropbox API v2 has function for this:

```
[[[dropboxClient.filesRoutes listFolderLongpoll:cursor] setResponseBlock:...];
```

Cursor parameter is returned by `listFolder` or `listFolderContinue`.